# Type conversion vs type cast

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion

In Go, because of it's static type language we can see lot of type conversion for example,

```
var x float64
var y =32
x=float64(32)
```

Even though Go supports type casting, as far as I know it's very rarely used in. Can someone explain why and usecases that type casting can be used. Following is a one example that use type casting.

```
type Common struct {
        Gender int
        From   string
        To     string
    }

    type Foo struct {
        Id    string
        Name  string
        Extra Common
    }

    type Bar struct {
        Id    string
        Name  string
        Extra Common
    }
    foo:=Foo{
        Id:"123",
        Name:"damitha",
        Extra: struct {
            Gender int
            From   string
            To     string
        }{Gender:1 , From:"xx", To:"yy" },
    }
    bar:=*(*Bar)(unsafe.Pointer(&foo))
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n",bar)
```

Even this mapping also possible to achieve in more safer ways.

Comment: Go does not have type cast; it has type conversions only and you are right: those are not uncommon. Your example uses package unsafe and you simply should not use this package. Your „example“ could be written as a type conversion in a safe way. What is the actual question/problem?

Comment: I want to find goland type casting usecases. If you say go doesn't support type casting it's ok. Eventhough my example(yes it's not recommended way) use type casting right

Comment: @DamithaDayananda The unsafe shenanigans in the question are similar to type casting, but such shenanigans are not required.  Use a conversion.

Comment: You can just [search for unsafe.Pointer](https://golang.org/search?q=unsafe.Pointer#Textual) to find uses in the standard library. Projects like sourcegraph.com can show uses in other open source projects. It's mostly used to interface with non-Go libraries.

Comment: "Even though Go supports type casting" -- No, Go does not support casting. You can fake it with the `unsafe` package, but that is decidedly _not_ supported.

Answer (score 4):

The unsafe shenanigans in the question are similar to type casting.  These shenanigans are not needed. Use a conversion:

```
bar := *(*Bar)(&foo)
```

or more simply:

```
bar := Bar(foo)
```

The relevant quote from the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) is:

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>
> - ...
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T have identical underlying types.
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T are pointer types that are not defined types, and their pointer base types have identical underlying types.

The first point in the quote applies to `Bar(foo)` because `Foo` and `Bar` have identical underlying types.

The second point in the quote applies to the conversion `(*Bar)(&foo)` because:

- `*Foo` and `*Bar` are pointer types
- `*Foo` and `*Bar` are not defined types.
- The base types `Foo` and `Bar` have the same underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

Go supports neither type casting nor implicit type conversion while lot of static support languages like Java C/C++ supporting both. Go only supports for type conversion.